# React Native FileSystem.GetInfoAsync doesn't return when a file was modified

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo-file-system

What I want to achieve with the below code is get info for individual files so that I can sort the files according to the modified time.

```
const permissions =
            await StorageAccessFramework.requestDirectoryPermissionsAsync();

        if (permissions.granted) {
            try {
                let uri = permissions.directoryUri;
                let files = await StorageAccessFramework.readDirectoryAsync(
                    uri
                );
                const fileObjects = [];

                for (const file of files) {
                    const fileStat = await getInfoAsync(
                        file
                    );
                                    
                    fileObjects.push({
                        uri: fileStat.uri,
                        time: fileStat.modificationTime,
                    });
                }
                        fileObjects.sort((a, b) => b.time - a.time);

                setStatusFiles(fileObjects);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
```

I tried logging the results of the function within the loop but I only get the following info.
{"exists": true, "isDirectory": false, "size": 109448, "uri": "content://com..."}